# Flutter : Wait for keyboard dismissed then call navigator.pop

Tags: flutter, dart

In screen B, there is a `TextField` with leading back icon on `AppBar`, when the user taps the leading "back" icon to return to screen A while the keyboard is open, it closes the keyboard and returns to screen A as expected, but there is a small glitch in screen A, it looks like the keyboard is not completely dismissed. its look like small vibration, disturbance on UI.

I tried to make a little adjustment with this code :

```dart
onPressed: () async {
  FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 300));
  Navigator.maybePop(context);
},
```

And the glitches on screen A are gone. but this method makes use of the `context` between `async` gaps which is not recommended by dart, any other way to solve this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Okay at the end of screen B try creating this class:

```
class AlwaysDisabledFocusNode extends FocusNode {
  @override
  bool get hasFocus => false;
}
```

then in your function try this:

```
onPressed: () async {
  AlwaysDisabledFocusNode();
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 300));
if(mounted) return;
  Navigator.maybePop(context);
},
```